# HTML - Почему не работает неразрывный пробел между текстом и картинкой?

Tags: html, css

Почему не работает неразрывный пробел между текстом и картинкой в первом блоке?
Во втором блоке неразрывный пробел между двумя кусками текста работает нормально!
Как сделать так чтоб картинка не переносилась на вторую строчку при уменьшении ширины окна.
http://jsfiddle.net/c9q6v1r8/2/

```html
<div>
  text-text-text-text-text&nbsp;<img src="http://www.sitehere.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/medal_award_bronze16.png">
</div>

<div>
  text-text-text-text-text-1&nbsp;text-text-text-text-text-2
</div>
```

Comment: Подробнее о неразрывных пробелах https://domhtml.ru/nerazryvnyj-probel-html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Чтобы работал между текстом и картинкой неразрывный пробел нужно в стилях для img указать `display: block;`
Пример:

```css
img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  text-text-text-text-text&nbsp;<img src="http://www.sitehere.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/medal_award_bronze16.png">
</div>
```

2) Чтобы картинка не переносилась на другую строчку, ставим `white-space: nowrap;`
Пример:

```css
.wsnw {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wsnw">
      text-text-text-text-text&nbsp;<img src="http://www.sitehere.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/medal_award_bronze16.png">
    </div>
```

Если вы имели в виду другое, чтобы текст ходил по строчкам, и картинка была справа, то:

```css
.wsnw img {
        float: right;
        padding-left: 5px;
}

p {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wsnw">
<p><img src="http://www.sitehere.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/medal_award_bronze16.png">text-text-text-text-text text-text-text-t text-text text-text-text zzzzzz</p></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Классно! Подходит!